Kotlin send email with attachment using Gmail in Google Cloud Run with service account secret stored in Google Cloud Secret Manager
I am trying to send email in my Kotlin application that runs on Google Cloud Run. This is the approach that I am going for:

Read Excel: Excel sheet is stored in the project under tmp/fortra-licenses.xlsx.
Read service account key: Key is stored in Google Cloud Secret Manager
Send email: Using Gmailer class

My error is that Gmailer class gives the following errors:

Unresolved reference 'transport'.
Unresolved reference 'jsonFactory'.
Argument type mismatch: actual type is 'com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials!', but 'com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer!' was expected.
Unresolved reference 'toByteArray'.

What can I do to fix the errors?
build.gradle.kts
I have added the implementations google-cloud-secretmanager, api-client:google-api-client, google-api-services-gmail, mail and activation.
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "2.0.20"

}

group = "com.cdcadvania"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.google.cloud:google-cloud-secretmanager:2.54.0")
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.11.0") // For JSON parsing
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.14") // For making HTTP requests
    implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.3.0") // Excel

    // Gmail API
    implementation("com.google.api-client:google-api-client:2.7.0")
    implementation("com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev110-1.25.0")
    implementation("javax.mail:mail:1.4")
    implementation("javax.activation:activation:1.1.1")




    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}



tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
tasks.jar {
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.demo.MainKt" // Replace with your main class
    }
}

kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(20)
}

Main.kt
In my main class I read the excel-file named "fortra-licenses.xlsx" and send it.
fun main() {
    // Write to Excel
        val excelFilePath = "tmp/fortra-licenses.xlsx"


        // Email: Read Excel file as byte array
        val excelFile = File(excelFilePath)
        val excelBytes = excelFile.readBytes()

        // Email: Email the Excel file
        val gmailer = Gmailer(projectId = "GCP-PROJECT-ID", secretId = "gmailer-google-service-account", emailFrom = "NOREPLY@MYDOMAIN.com")

        gmailer.send(
            emailTo = "ME@MYDOMAIN.com",
            emailSubject = "License Report",
            emailContent = "<html><head></head><body><p>Attached is the license usage report.</p></body></html>",
            emailAttachmentFileName = excelFile.name,
            emailAttachmentBytes = excelBytes,
            emailAttachmentBytesType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
        )
}

Gmailer.kt
My main email class that I use to send emails. This is the one that gives me errors:

Unresolved reference: transport
Unresolved reference: jsonFactory
credentials: Type mismatch.
toByteArray(): Unresolved reference.

Code:
import com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message
import com.google.gson.JsonParser
import java.util.*
import javax.activation.DataHandler
import javax.activation.DataSource
import javax.mail.Session
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart
import javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource
import java.util.Base64

/**
 * A utility class for sending emails using the Gmail API and a Google Service Account.
 *
 * This class handles authentication via Google Service Account credentials and supports
 * sending plain text or HTML emails, with or without attachments.
 *
 * ### Features:
 * - Authenticate using Google Service Account.
 * - Send emails with optional reply-to address.
 * - Attach files of any type to emails.
 *
 * Updated: 18.11.2024 by Ditlefsen
 * Version: 1.0
 */
class Gmailer(
    private val projectId: String,
    private val secretId: String,
    private val emailFrom: String
) {

    private val logHeadline = "Gmailer::"
    private var service: Gmail
    private var secretJson: Map<String, String>

    init {
        println("$logHeadline Initializing Gmailer...")

        // Load secret from Google Secret Manager
        val secretStr = googleSecretManagerAccessSecretVersion(projectId, secretId)
        secretJson = try {
            JsonParser.parseString(secretStr).asJsonObject.entrySet().associate { it.key to it.value.asString }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException("$logHeadline The secret $secretId is not valid JSON: ${e.message}")
        }

        // Login to the Gmail service
        service = serviceAccountLogin()
    }

    private fun serviceAccountLogin(): Gmail {
        println("$logHeadline Logging into Gmail with service account...")

        val credentialsStream = secretJson["private_key"]?.byteInputStream()
            ?: throw RuntimeException("$logHeadline Missing private key in secret JSON.")

        val credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(credentialsStream).createScoped(
            listOf("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send")
        )

        return Gmail.Builder(
            credentials.transport,
            credentials.jsonFactory,
            credentials
        )
            .setApplicationName("Gmailer")
            .build()
    }

    fun send(
        emailReplyTo: String? = null,
        emailTo: String,
        emailSubject: String,
        emailContent: String,
        emailAttachmentFileName: String? = null,
        emailAttachmentBytes: ByteArray? = null,
        emailAttachmentBytesType: String? = null
    ) {
        println("$logHeadline Sending email to $emailTo...")

        // Create MIME email message
        val session = Session.getDefaultInstance(Properties())
        val mimeMessage = MimeMessage(session).apply {
            setFrom(InternetAddress(emailFrom))
            setRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress(emailTo))
            replyTo = emailReplyTo?.let { arrayOf(InternetAddress(it)) } ?: emptyArray()
            subject = emailSubject

            // Add content
            val contentPart = MimeBodyPart().apply { setContent(emailContent, "text/html") }
            val multipart = MimeMultipart().apply { addBodyPart(contentPart) }

            // Add attachment if provided
            if (!emailAttachmentFileName.isNullOrEmpty() && emailAttachmentBytes != null && emailAttachmentBytesType != null) {
                val (mimeType, subType) = emailAttachmentBytesType.split("/")
                val attachmentPart = MimeBodyPart().apply {
                    dataHandler = DataHandler(ByteArrayDataSource(emailAttachmentBytes, emailAttachmentBytesType))
                    fileName = emailAttachmentFileName
                }
                multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart)
            }

            setContent(multipart)
        }

        // Encode and send email
        val encodedMessage = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(mimeMessage.toByteArray())
        val message = Message().apply { raw = encodedMessage }

        try {
            val sentMessage = service.users().messages().send("me", message).execute()
            println("$logHeadline Email sent to $emailTo with ID: ${sentMessage.id}")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException("$logHeadline Error sending email: ${e.message}")
        }
    }
}

googleSecretManagerAccessSecretVersion.kt
The secret code is read from Google Cloud Secret Manager.
The secret is stored like a JSON:
{
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "client_email": ".....@......iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "......",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metad...",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nM...a\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "private_key_id": "b...............",
  "project_id": "............",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "type": "service_account"
}

Code to read secret:
import com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.AccessSecretVersionRequest
import com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.SecretManagerServiceClient

/**
 * Reads a secret from Google Secret Manager
 * Documentation: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/secret-manager-python#6
 *
 * Updated: 18.11.2022 Ditlefsen
 * Version: 1.0
 * License: http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php GNU Public License
 */

fun googleSecretManagerAccessSecretVersion(projectId: String, secretId: String, versionId: String = "latest"): String {
    // Create the Secret Manager client
    SecretManagerServiceClient.create().use { client ->
        // Build the resource name of the secret version
        val secretName = "projects/$projectId/secrets/$secretId/versions/$versionId"

        // Access the secret version
        val request = AccessSecretVersionRequest.newBuilder().setName(secretName).build()
        val response = client.accessSecretVersion(request)

        // Return the decoded payload
        return response.payload.data.toStringUtf8()
    }
}

